# Does the resolution of the training and test set have to be the same?

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning

I wonder if the training set should have the same resolution as the test set. I would like to make a CNN for object recognition. My dataset is much clearer than the data I found on web. The problem is that I found only 30 objects in my dataset which I could label. The data from web has labeled over 200 pictures but the resolution is worse. Here is a sample of my data and the data from web: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6qa0.jpg.

Comment: Why exactly is this an `r` and `keras` question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents: it would definitely help if you had images with the same resolution.

When you load an image you get a matrix with a bunch of numbers for each pixel. Your neural network will try to identify patterns common to the labelled images and then look for those patterns in the test.

As the images differ thou, those patterns won't really be the same in the test dataset and this will definitely negatively affect the outcome.

A silly example would be if you are trying to identify antennas on the roof instead of the solar panels. In your image antennas have some kind of shape while in the web image they are just one pixel. This would make the testing dataset completely useless.

However, the solar panels in the two images have quite clear characteristics (shape, color, contrast, contour) and I believe you should still give it a try as the different resolution might not be extremely problematic in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Wouldn't the white frame in my pictures negatively affect the model?

Comment: I am honestly not sure about that but if I had to guess I would say no. However, you can and should mask those. Shouldn't be too hard as the pixels are going to have all the same value (1 in a b\w image) and they will have a quite specific position.